# How do I use localstorage to store text on a form and return it on another form in read-only format

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
<form action="apply.html" method="post">
  <div class="cloudinformation">
    <h2>
      Job reference number:
    </h2>
    <br>
    <h4>
    1FN43
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply">
  </div>
</form>

<form action="apply.html" method="post">
  <div class="cloudinformation">
    <h2>
      Job reference number:
    </h2>
    <br>
    <h4>
    6LZ9W
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply">
  </div>
</form>
```

I've got 3 different forms on 1 page and I need to use JavaScript to make it where, depending on which form I submit, the corresponding job reference number will be stored in local storage and displayed on another form on another page, the aforementioned 'apply.html' page in read-only form. I only know how to store an input but not text already on the form. Should I make 3 separate 'apply.html' pages for each form or how can I make it using 1 for all 3 forms.

Note: I cannot use jQuery.

```
<form action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" method="post" id="regform">
    
    <label>Job Reference Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="onlyletters" name="onlyletters" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" minlength="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="Reference number for specified job.." required="required">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required="required" maxlength="25" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required="required" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">
    <label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="trip-start" value="2021-08-30">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="gender"> Select you gender</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="gender" id="gender" required="required">
      <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="streetname">Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="streetname" name="streetname" required="required" placeholder="Your street name..." maxlength="40" />
    <label for="suburb">Suburb/Town</label>
    <input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb" required="required" placeholder="Your suburb/town..." maxlength="40">
    <label for="state">Choose a state:</label>
    <br>
    <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
      <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
      <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
      <option value="NT">NT</option>
      <option value="WA">WA</option>
      <option value="SA">SA</option>
      <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
      <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" required="required" placeholder="Your postcode..." maxlength="4" minlength="4" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="emailadd" placeholder="Your email address.." required="required">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phonenumb" placeholder="e.g. 0451124561" minlength="8" maxlength="12" required="required">
    <input type="submit" value="Apply">
  </form>
```

Comment: `I only know how to store an input but not text already on the form.` Can you explain this ?

Comment: As in, the job reference number is a constant and not something you have to input. I'd only know how to store it if it was an input that asked you for a job reference number.

Comment: Take a look at [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). This should help you access a text value from the DOM.

Comment: Alternatively you can add an [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/hidden), if you have the hand on the form. This way you will be able to access this value on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are showing us, I tend to believe that the first forms designed to pass job references to the real applying form are overkill.
I think a simple link would be enough. For instance:

```
<div class="cloudinformation">
    <h2>
      Job reference number:
    </h2>
    <br>
    <h4>6LZ9W<h4>
    <br>
     
    <a href="apply.html?job_reference=6LZ9W">Apply</a>
</div>
```

After you can easily access job reference in javascript from the apply page:

```
// Retrieve job_reference from url parameter.
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let jobReference = params.get('job_reference');

// Set the form input value
document.querySelector('#onlyletters').value = jobReference;
```

[URL.searchParams documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

[document.querySelector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked except that, for some reason, I cannot store it and retrieve it. Would you know how I can use JavaScript to store it and retrieve it on another form?

Comment: What does `apply.html` looks like ?

Comment: Would you like me to upload the code here in the comments?

Comment: Better add it to your question. Hard to know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Done. Keep in mind that the job reference section for apply.html will be replaced by what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer, as I think you are misleading with your current form with job_reference. I tend to believe that what you are looking for are hypertext links, rather than forms.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I'm meant to implement this? I've never seen or used this function before and can't find material on it. Sorry but I'm quite new to JavaScript and I know this might be quite annoying.

Comment: http://web.simmons.edu/~grabiner/comm244/weeknine/including-javascript.html

Comment: I've done that already but nothing happens, which makes sense because I don't see how it will actually appear on apply.html since you don't dictate where you want it. I don't see how it's being retrieved on apply.html.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had already the part where you set your input value up and running. I gave an example of how you can set the input value in javascript.

Comment: Thank you. That's a mistake on my part. Thanks for the help and your persistence in helping me. I'll try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Is that jQuery by any chance? I left a note on the question stating that I can't use that. Maybe you accidentally missed it?

Comment: Nope, as you can see in the documentation, it's part of the standard DOM specification and is widely supported.

Comment: I really do apologise for this but can you elaborate on exactly where the JavaScript goes? I don't see how to actually implement that code in apply.html

I really do apologise.

Comment: You need to insert a script tag at the end of your body section as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/2595406). This ensures the page is correctly loaded before running, and that the input you are trying to value is present. Then the piece of code I provided  is supposed to retrieve the job_reference from the URL and set the proper input with this value.